Video about princess interacting with dinosaurs and a blob creature living with family
So I remember seeing and hearing about this video that was VHS originally but was uploaded to YouTube.
It had I think 3 stories in it, but I only remember 2 of them. It was narrated by an older woman/older sounding woman. Forgot her name.
The 1st was about this princess that I think went back in time and was interacting with dinosaurs, to give them feathers I think for whatever reason
The 2nd had this boy make a blob creature called Bob The Blob(iirc) somehow and then after that it started living with him and eventually the boy made Bob a house made out of toy blocks/bricks. Then a cockroach befriends Bob, but it eventually either dies or sacrifices itself(I think they got trapped somewhere without food), and Bob eats it. Eventually, I kid you not, it crawls up the butt of either a rat or cat. I forgot what happened afterwards.
Anyone remember what video I am describing?

The Films of Nanny Lynn

It consists of an anthology film format of three independent short stories, narrated by a woman voice, "Princess Emiluma," "The Story of Srebrenica" and "Bob the Blob."

They are ... erm ... extraordinary! They remind me of the South Park cartoons in both style and content, but they are weirder than anything South Park did.
If you search for it on YouTube you'll find lots of uploads of it.

Huh. Apparently the creator is in contact with the Reddit community and there are two more videos uploaded with many others that she made lost to time because they were made entirely to amuse her grandchildren.
